# How can symbols be used in a Shiny table header?

Tags: r, shiny, symbols

> **Objective:** Use math symbols in column titles for a Shiny App.

For example, x-bar or beta, alpha etc.

Below is what I've tried, which yields strange results (see image).

I've also tried using and expression, which gave this error: `Warning: Error in as.data.frame.default: cannot coerce class ""expression"" to a data.frame`

**ui.R file:**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("mytable"),
    tableOutput("mytable2")
  )
))
```

**server.R file:**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  mytable <- reactive({
    iris2 <- iris
    colnames(iris2) <-  c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width","$m^r_t$", "$\\delta p_t$","$R^r_t$")
  })

  output$mytable <-  renderTable(head(iris,5))
  output$mytable2 <-  renderTable(mytable())

})
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to rely on html using unicode characters for the table header than R:

```
  output$mytable2 <-  renderTable({mytable()},include.colnames=FALSE,
                                  add.to.row = list(pos = list(0), 
                                  command = " <tr> <th> &#931 </th> <th> &#963;</th> <th> &#7839;</th> <th> &#127137;</th> <th>  &#x263A; </th>  </tr>" ))
```

[image]