# Is there documentation for uncommon arguments in R Shiny renderTable?

Tags: shiny, document

I am using the solution to the following question:

[How can symbols be used in a Shiny table header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112679/how-can-symbols-be-used-in-a-shiny-table-header)

*My* question is >> does anyone know where there might be some reference material for the uncommon arguments?  I've looked at the R documentation and have come up short.

I'm referring to arguments such as 'include.colnames', and 'add.to.row' from @Minnow's code in the answer to the original question.  Here is the code:

```
output$mytable2 <-  renderTable({mytable()},include.colnames=FALSE,
                                  add.to.row = list(pos = list(0), 
                                  command = " <tr> <th> &#931 </th> <th> &#963;</th> <th> &#7839;</th> <th> &#127137;</th> <th>  &#x263A; </th>  </tr>" ))
```

Any breadcrumbs are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is more documentation inside `shiny`/the used packages, but it's a bit hidden. If you look at the documentation of `help(renderTable)`, you see that besides the explained arguments there is `...`. This means that the function passes further arguments to functions it calls. It is specified that `renderTable` will pass these additional arguments to `xtable::xtable()` and `xtable::print.xtable()`. So it's a good idea to look at these help pages, and indeed you find the documentation for `add.to.row` there.

Comment: To clarify the answer provided by @starja,  `add.to.row` belongs to the `xtable::print.xtable()` function.